# Objective-c How to send a (void) in parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, call

i would like to know how can i pass in parameter the "address" of a void ?

```
- (void) showWithLabel:(id)method {

...
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(method) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

}


- (void) test:{
sleep(3)
}

- (void) hello:{

[self showWithLabel:(id)test]
}
```

But that doesnt work (build error)

Answer (score 4):

To pass a selector, you need the following keywords :

@selector and SEL.

So, in your example, it should be:

```
- (void) showWithLabel:(SEL)method {
```

and

```
[self showWithLabel:@selector(test)]
```

To call the selector :
    [target performSelector:method]

As Kubi points out, you should be very careful with the colon.
There is no colon if there is no parameter.
BUT, if you have parameters, you must realize that the colon is a part of the selector's name.
For example:

```
-(void) test //no parameter gives @selector(test)

-(void) testWithName:(NSString*)name //1 parameter gives @selector(testWithName:)

-(void) testWithName:(NSString*)name andAge:(int)age //2paramater gives selector gives @selector(testWithName:andAge:)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "a void". `void` is a C keyword that, when applied to a pointer, means that the pointer is untyped, i.e. the type is unknown or not important. I've noticed recently that some beginners seem to refer to a void method or function (that is, a method or function that doesn't return a value) as "a void", but this is not common usage.

I can't tell from the code you posted what you want to pass or where you'd like to pass it. Could you revise your question to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Also notice that I removed the colons on your `test` and `hello` methods. In Obj-C a colon delineates method parameters and since you had no parameters, you need no colons.

```
- (void) showWithLabel:(SEL)method {
    //...
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:method onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}


- (void) test {
    sleep(3)
}

- (void) hello {
    [self showWithLabel:@selector(test)]
}
```